# ESRI ArcGIS plot point

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point, java

I have created a Java function to plot the points on the map, and I need to pass the x-y coordinates and the taskevent as the parameters. I would like to ask what should be the input parameter for taskevent??

```
    public void plotCase(TaskEvent event){
    
      event.getWebContext().getWebMap();
    
    }
```